# Site provoking error in Microsoft Edge (but not any other browsers)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, microsoft-edge

When loading a page on our site in Microsoft Edge, you *sometimes* see the following error (that is, it happens about 1/3 times):

> **This page is having a problem loading**
>
> We tried to load this page for you a few times, but there is still a
>   problem with this site. We know you have better things to do than to
>   watch this page reload over and over again so try coming back to this
>   page later.

The page looks like it reloads once or twice before showing the error. We don't see the same issue in any other major browser (IE 9-11, Chrome, FireFox, etc.), and there are no console errors (although there are a couple of warnings).

Here are the console warnings that are shown:

- The code on this page disabled back and forward caching
- Malformed comment. Comments should start with `<!--`. (Specifically referring to lines of code that include conditional formatting for earlier versions of IE.)

Here's an example of a page on our site where we've seen this error: https://casetext.com/case/cole-taylor-bank-v-corrigan

For what it's worth, we're an AngularJS website on version 1.4.4 and we're using ui-router for routing.

Comment: It seems you have outsourced data crucial for the understanding of your question. Please post all relevant code, images and resources **in the question itself**, if the link dies or changes your question will lose most if not all of its meaning!

Comment: Have you inspected the network traffic? Anything suspicious?

Comment: @kyll don't forget your new ability to cast close votes ;-)

Comment: @Kyll: For what it's worth, I've added the two warnings in the console and the precise error from Microsoft Edge, as well as the framework we're using (AngularJS 1.4.4) and the routing tooling we're using (ui-router). I'm not sure what else I can provide -- the bug is definitely a mystery -- but I'd be happy to provide more if it'd be helpful. Also happy to take out the link.

Comment: @Kyll: sorry, but I think I'm missing something -- what should I provide in the question that I haven't yet provided? Everything I said in the comment was already in the question. Not trying to be difficult -- I genuinely want to see an answer and I would love to provide any information that would help get there.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding, my comment lacked precision: I meant an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), something to help up reproduce the issue even sporadically.

Comment: Gotcha. I'll have to think about what to do here. The bug is such a mystery -- and I've had so much trouble trying to reproduce myself -- that I was sort of hoping someone familiar with Edge has seen this before and knows what's up. I don't eve know where to start digging.